# Complexity Analysis of the following loops

Tags: complexity-theory

I have some exercises of complexity analysis of double loops, and I don't know if I'm doing them correctly.

```py
for i = 1 to n do 
    j = i
    while j < n do 
        j = 2∗j 
    end while 
end for
```

My answer on this is `O(n^2)`, because the first loop is running `O(n)` times and the inner one is doing  `O(n/2)` iterations for the "worst" iteration of the outer loop. So `O(n) * O(n/2) = O(n^2)`.

Also looking a bit further, I think I can say that the inner loops is doing a partial sum that is `O(n/2) + O(n-1) + ... + O(1)`, and this is also `O(n)`

---

```py
        for i = 1 to n do 
            j = n 
            while i∗i < j do 
                j = j − 1 
            end while 
        end for
```

Again the outer loop is `O(n)`, and the inner loop is doing `O(sqrt(n))` in the worst iteration, so here I think it's `O(n*sqrt(n))` but I'm unsure about this one.

---

```py
       for i = 1 to n do 
            j = 2 
            while j < i do 
                j = j ∗j 
            end while 
        end for
```

Here the outer loop is `O(n)` and the inner loop is doing `O(logn)` work for the worst case. Hence I think this is `O(nlogn)`

---

```py
        i = 2 
        while (i∗i < n) and (n mod i != 0) do 
            i = i + 1 
        end while
```

Finally, I don't know how to make sense of this one. Because of the modulus operator.

---

My questions are:

1. Did I do anything wrong in the first 3 examples?
2. Is the "**worst-case approach**" for the inner loops I'm doing correct?
3. How should I approach the last exercise?

Comment: Yes, the initial though was correct. Every `j` is equal to `i * 2^x`, therefore you can do at most `log2 n` iterations in the inner loop. The complexity cannot be worst than `O(n log n)`. It's a question whether it is actually lower or not.

Comment: The second case is interesting because once `i >= sqrt(n)` the second loop won't run at all. for `i < sqrt(n)` it will do `n - i^2` iterations. That means something like `O(sqrt(n) * n + n - sqrt(n))` which I guess would be `O(n * sqrt(n))` in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question:
The inner loop takes `log(n/i)` time. an upper bound is `O(log(n))` giving a total time of `O(n*log(n))`. a lower bound is `log(n/2)` and sum only on the last `n/2` terms, giving a total complexity of `n/2 * log(n/2) = n/2*log(n) - n/2 = O(n * log(n))` and we get that the bound `O(n* log(n))` is tight (we have a theta bound).

Second Question:
The inner loop takes `n - i^2` time (and `O(1)` if `i^2 >= n`). Notice that for `i >= sqrt(n)` the inner loop takes `O(1)` time so we can run the outer loop only for `i in 1:sqrt(n)` and add `O(n)` to the result. An upper bound is `n` for the inner loop, giving a total time of `O(n * sqrt(n) + n) = O(n ^ (3/2))`. A lower bound is `3/4 * n` for the inner loop and summing only for `i`'s up to `sqrt(n) / 2` (so that `i^2 < n / 4` and `n - i ^ 2 > 3/4 * n` ) and we get a total time of `Ω(sqrt(n) / 2 * n * 3/4 + n) = Ω(n^(3/2))` thus the bound `O(n * sqrt(n))` is indeed tight.

Third Question:
In this one `j` is starting from 2 and we square it until it reaches `i`. after `t` steps of the inner loop, `j` is equal to `2^(2^t)`. we reach `i` when `j = 2 ^ (log(i)) = 2 ^ (2 ^ log(log(i)))`, i.e., after `t = log(log(i))` steps. We can again give an upper bound and lower bound similarly to the previous questions, and get the tight bound `O(n * log(log(n)))`.

Forth Question:
The complexity can vary between `2 = O(1)` and `sqrt(n)`, depending on the factorization of `n`. In the worst case, `n` is a perfect square, giving a complexity of `O(sqrt(n)`

To answer your questions at the end:
1. Yes, you have done some things wrong. You have reached wrong answers in 1 and 3 and in 2 your result is right but the reasoning is flawed; the inner loop is not `O(sqrt(n))`, as you have already seen in my analysis.
2. Considering the "worst case" for the inner loop is good, as it's giving you an upper bound (which is mostly accurate in this kind of questions), but to establish a tight bound you must also show a lower bound, usually by taking only the higher terms and lowering them to the first, as I did in some of the examples. Another way to prove tight bounds is to use formulas of known series such as `1 + ... + n` = `n * (n + 1) / 2`, giving an immediate bound of `O(n^2)` instead of getting the lower bound by `1 + ... + n >= n/2 + ... + n >= n/2 + ... + n/2 = n/2 * n/2 = n^/4 = Ω(n^2)`.
3. Answered above.

Comment: Could you please explain why in the third case j is equal to `2^(2^t)` and not to 2^t ?

Comment: you start with 2=2^(2^0). If `j` was `2^(2^t)` and we squared it, we would get `j = (2^(2^t))^2 = 2^((2^t) * 2) = 2^(2^(t+1))`. Thus at the `t` step we have `j = 2^(2^t)`

Answer (score 1):

For the first one in the inner loop we have:
`i, 2*i, 4*i, ... , (2^k)*i` where `(2^k)*i < n`. So `k < logn - logi`. The outer loop as you said repeats `n+1` times. In total we have this sum:

[image: one]

Which equals to

[image: sec]

Therefore I think the complexity should be `O(nlogn)`.

---

For the second one we have:

[image: thi]

---

For third one:

[image: fo]

So I think it should be `O(log(n!))`

---

For the last one, if `n` is even, it will be `O(1)` because we don't enter the loop. But the worst case is when `n` is odd and is not divisible by any of the square numbers, then I think it should be

[image: fif]

Comment: I think that the second will be much less. You have to split the `1... n` interval at `sqrt(n)` because any `i > sqrt(n)` won't run the inner loop at all. `O(n^2)` is obviously too much.

Comment: yes from `sqrt(n)` forward, the inner loop doesn't run. The last sentence calculated is `n - (sqrt(n))^2` which is for `i = sqrt(n)` and the ones after that are ignored.

Comment: However, your last statement `n^2 - (n^3/2)` cannot be just reduced to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: It is `O(n^2 - n^(1.5))` which I think is reducible to `O(n^2)`. But  `O(n^2 - n^(1.5))`  is more exact.

Comment: Nope, it can be further reduced to `n * (1 - sqrt(n))` which looks much less than just `n^2`. In my opinion `O(n * sqrt(n))` would be considered the correct answer here.

Comment: wouldn't that be negative?

Comment: Oh god, I am probably tired. You are right, I am doing something wrong but `O(n^2)` is definitely too much.